# Changing private fields in Java using public methods

Tags: java, c++

In C++ there is a way to change data even if it's private:

```
class Foo
{
private:
    char * i;
public:
    char * getInt() {return i;};
    Foo() {i="Winter";};
}

int main()
{
  Foo a;
  strcpy(a.getInt(), "Summer"); //it changes i
  cout<<a.getInt(); //gives "Summer"

  return 0;
}
```

Is there some way to do that in Java?

EDIT: If there is, then is there some keyword like `const` in C++, to prevent such behaviour?

Comment: If the variable is a mutable object, you can do exactly the same in Java as well. The difference is merely that Strings in Java are not mutable.

Comment: There is no way to "prevent" such behavior.  If you use a mutable variable type and let it get returned out to users, it can be modified; if you use an immutable type or copy mutable types before they are accessed by getters, it can't be modified.

Comment: You can use reflection to mess even with immutable objects.

Comment: Note that the C++ code presented here has undefined behavior.

Comment: @Pete Becker Because it's possible to pass as the second arg a string which is longer than there is space in class field? Or is there anything else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java returns copies of pointers to objects (and copies of the value of primitives). A `String` is such an object. E.g.

```
class Foo {
    private String i = "Winter";
    public String get() { return i; }
}
```

Now that is perfectly safe and nothing (except reflection) can change your private field or it's state:

```
void main() {
  Foo a = new Foo();
  String i = a.get();
  String j = i + " rocks"; // creates a new string
  i = "Summer"; // now points to another string
  System.out.println(a.get()); // still prints "Winter"
}
```

However, if code is able to modify the returned object, you can't prevent that it changes it.

Java also has no builtin way to make objects immutable, you must design them to be effectively immutable, like the `String` class for example. Every method that "modifies" a string actually creates a new immutable string that can be shared among all places & threads without worries.

If your class was

```
class Foo {
    public String i = "Winter";
}
```

you wouldn't be safe. Code could change what that field points to.

```
void main() {
  Foo a = new Foo();
  a.i = "Summer"; // that works.
  System.out.println(a.i); // prints "Summer"
}
```

While you shouldn't have public fields especially if you don't want it to be modified, there is something that helps: `final`.

```
class Foo {
    public final String i = "Winter";
}
void main() {
  Foo a = new Foo();
  a.i = "Summer"; // Error: final field cannot be modified.
}
```

The `final` keyword guarantees that a field is assigned exactly once. The field needs to have a value after the constructor finishes, and it cannot be changed afterwards. The referenced object however may still be mutable, merely the reference to it isn't.